# NotImplementedException in the System.Security.Cryptography package

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, mscorlib

i've been struggling for a few days trying to get this package to work. Does anyone have any idea why specifically in Unity this package is not implemented? Upon using a method in the package, i'll take for example the `CngKey.Import` method throws the following:

```
NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Import(System.Byte[] keyBlob, 
System.Security.Cryptography.CngKeyBlobFormat format)
```

What i've tried:

- Using in a new console project in Visual Studio - this works fine.
- Using on my other computer which is a mac, looks like this package isn't even recognized on mac.
- Dragging the .dlls into Unity.
- Installing all cryptography packages from nuget.
- Trying to re-add any references in visual studio.
- Updating Unity to the latest release.

It may be this package is not supported, but i thought i'd ask before posting an issue on github. Thank you, hugely appreciated :)

Edit1: Added a small example of using the code.
In my editor the text is red, yet compiles and at runtime throws the NotImplementedException as stated above.

```
using (CngKey key = CngKey.Import(new byte[] { 2 }, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPrivateBlob))
{

}
```

Comment: Post the Cryptography code

Comment: Have you tried this: https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-use-system-security-cryptography-xml.464777/

Comment: @Programmer I did post a small snippet, it's in a large context normally spanning multiple files but no methods work when singled out either.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Yeah i've tried that thanks, did not seem to do much.